# Javascript Animation: fadein complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Hey I have some code that animates images to be used as a banner ad. Currently it rotates through the images in an infinite loop. I want to change the behavior so that it stops after 1 iteration.

My thought was that a complete function needs to be added somewhere in the below code:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.fadein :first-child').next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
        }, 2000);
    } );
    </script>
```

Comment: my thought is that if you remove setInterval, the code will only run once - but that seems way too obvious

Comment: Yeah that swapped the image over, which I will still need

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many images there are you could always use a loop.

```
i = 0
while (i < <num_images>) {
    //your code here
}
```

This way it will only run once over each image.